# Why does this code work for the current term but not the parent term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

This code below displays the current taxonomy term on a taxonomy term page

```
$current = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2)); ?>
if ($current): ?>
echo $current->name; ?>
endif; ?>
```

The code below displays the error: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 9 of...)  Line 9 is "echo $parent->name;"

```
$parent = taxonomy_get_parents($current->tid);
if ($parent){
echo $parent->name;
}?>
```

I'm really confused as to why the first set of code works but the 2nd doesn't? "print_r($parent);" displays the info below, so the data is there.

Array ( [3218] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 3218 [vid] => 12 [name] => NAME OF TAXONOMY TERM [description] => This is the description area [format] => full_html [weight] => 0 [vocabulary_machine_name] => mfr_model [field_displayed_view] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [vname] => final_term_pages|testing [vargs] => ) ) ) [metatags] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [title] => Array ( [value] => This is the meta page title ) [description] => Array ( [value] => This is the meta description ) ) ) ) )

Comment: I should say that both these groups of code are in the same newly formed block using  the php filter.

Comment: Because `taxonomy_get_parents` returns _An array of term objects..._?

Comment: I know very little about php, but I see that now. If I print $current, it shows as a "stdClass Object" and not an array as the second group of code.  My question would be then, how do I print the [name} part of the array only?

Comment: There are quite a few ways - `$x = array_shift($parent); echo $x->name;` would be one. `echo reset($parent)->name;` would be another, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the docs for [taxonomy_get_parents()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents/7) you can see that the return value is an array of parent terms.

So you might loop through the results like this:

```
$parents = taxonomy_get_parents($current->tid);
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
  echo $parent->name;
}
```

or use just the first one like this:

```
$parents = taxonomy_get_parents($current->tid);
if ($parents) {
  echo $parents[0]->name;
}
```